# using lwuit UI library I am not destroy j2me application

Tags: java-me, lwuit, lwuit-form

I am working with j2me using lwuit I have one problem is that

when I am `startApp()` inside midlet I first set `Display.init(this)`

and run application lwuit work good but when I am using Form inside `startApp()` event in midlet it good work but in this form actionevent I am call new form and in this new form 
I put one back command when I pressed it it does not move on main midlet

please help how know lwuit use

```
import javax.microedition.MIDlet;

import  some lwuit UILibrary

public class mainMiddlet extends MIDlet implement ActionListner
{
      public mainMiddlet(){
                  try{

                       Display.init(this);
                       //somthing is here 
                       form=new Form();

                       form.addActionListener(this);

                     }catch(Exception e){}
       }
       public void actionperformed(ActionEven ae){
                //here i call new form 
                //in action event of this form 
                new form().show();
        }
       //here some middlet default method 


}
public class newForm extends Form {

    //in this form I am put one command back and when i am pressed it 
    // I call mainMiddlet but it throw error internal application java.lang.nullpointer
   // can I back on mainmiddlet from on form to another form 
   // my main problem is I am not move on mainmiddlet for exit middlet because destoryall()
   // is method of middlet 

}
```

Comment: Did you add the command? I dont understand your coding? Is this full of your code?

Comment: ya i add command my problem is that when  mainMiddlet start can i destory from another form command event above in my code i have mainmiddlet i add one command Next and when i pressed it move on another form(new form)but from there i can not back on mainMiddlet it throws error java.lang.error.nullpointherException

Answer (score 0):

Its just simple. You can call the `show()` method inside next form back command. For example,

**MainMidlet.java**

```
// create the midlet and write inside of the midlet
final Form form = new Form();

form.addCommand(new Command("Next") {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            new NewForm(form).show();
       }
    });
```

**NewForm.java**

```
   // create the NewForm class and write inside of the class

        public NewForm(final Form form) {
   // Constructor
        addCommand(new Command("Back") {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                    form.show();
               }
            });
    }
```

Comment: Hi Thank for consideration But When i call form.show() which is object extends midlet class so when i pressed in new form back command as you mention in above code it will throw exception java.lang.nullpointe Exception Please Help Me ..............